# Having a problem with local optima how to write Move or Accpetor with SpringBoot to search wider space

Tags: java, spring-boot, optaplanner

I have an airline problem where I have a Seat and it gets assigned a Passenger based on a preference and weight (basically a Bid). I want the top passengers with highest Bids assigned to be rewarded for their assigned Seat.  Looking at the logs it looks like the Solver is performing "accepted/selected move" on similar Passengers with similar bids and I want it to select Passengers with different bids.

I want to accept a move on different Bids for different seats and explore a wider space.

I couldn't find any sample about how to write either a Move or Acceptor and then how to have SpringBoot use this new class.  But maybe I'm just missing a setting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding a specific **move selector** can help with this problem. This can be a generic move (such as **pillar swaps**) or a **custom move**. No point in changing the `Acceptor`.

I presume you have a hard constraint to keep families together (= seated next to each other), especially a toddler with their parent. If you turn on TRACE logging (not just DEBUG), you'll see that it does evaluate moves that change the toddler's seat, but it never selects them as the winning step, because of that hard constraint (the parent didn't change seat in the same move).

So the trick is to have a move that moves both the toddler and its parent together.

Add a `src/main/resources/solverConfig.xml` file (location can be customized with `optaplanner.solver-config-xml` in `application.properties`. Have it contain something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver xmlns="https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/solver" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/solver https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/solver/solver.xsd">
  <constructionHeuristic/>
  <localSearch>
    <unionMoveSelector>
      <changeMoveSelector/>
      <swapMoveSelector/>
      ... <!-- Add your custom move factory/iterator here -->
    </unionMoveSelector>
  </localSearch>
</solver>
```

Always keep a change and swap move selector in the mix too. Keep an eye on your score calculation speed (last INFO log message) before and after these changes. Read about JUST_IN_TIME selection.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  I didn't know we could have a solverConfig.xml in SpringBoot.  I'll try the move selector.

Comment: Geoffrey De Smet, in a simple example from the doc 6.4.1. Filtered move selection, this would seem to be what I'm looking for, a simple check.  Why would this not work? public class DifferentCourseSwapMoveFilter implements SelectionFilter<CourseSchedule, SwapMove> {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(ScoreDirector<CourseSchedule> scoreDirector, SwapMove move) {
        Lecture leftLecture = (Lecture) move.getLeftEntity();
        Lecture rightLecture = (Lecture) move.getRightEntity();
        return !leftLecture.getCourse().equals(rightLecture.getCourse());
    }

}

Comment: You need a bulk move that moves both the toddler and parent at the same time. The move selection filter cannot accomplish that, since it just filters move (and neither change moves nor swap moves are bulk moves; change move changes value for one entity, swap moves swap values between two entities). You need a double/triple swap move, a swap move that exchanges values of four or more pair of entities. A filtered move selector (to select only parent/child pairs) would work on the double/triple swap move, but not on the normal swap move.